# How to count how many people is using my bot?

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a bot stats command for my bot.
How do I find out how many people are using my bot?
Is there a way same as finding out how many guilds the bot is in? (`client.guilds.cache.size`)

Comment: What do you mean by "using"?

Comment: @Elitezen they mean have the bot in their server

Comment: `client.guilds.cache.size` already does that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```js
client.users.cache.size
```

---

Not counting bots:

```js
client.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot).size
```

Comment: Is this without bots?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a way to get the count skipping over bots

Answer (score 2):

You can use `client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => guild.memberCount).reduce((p, c) => p + c);`. If your bot is on 4 servers of 40 members, it will be 160.

Comment: Is this with bots?

Comment: Yes bots are counted.

Answer (score -1):

Do

```
client.user.setActivity(`on ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers.`, {
    type: "PLAYING",
});
```

It sets the presence to `Playing on x Servers.`